# Using IMAPClient how do you view the Senders address?

Tags: python, imaplib, imapclient

Using [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) how do I view the message body and the senders email address?

```
server = IMAPClient(imap_server, use_uid=True, ssl=ssl)
server.login(imap_user, imap_password)

print 'login successful'

select_info = server.select_folder('INBOX')
print '%d messages in INBOX' % select_info['EXISTS']

messages = server.search(['NOT DELETED'])
print "%d messages that aren't deleted" % len(messages)

print
print "Messages:"
response = server.fetch(messages, ['FLAGS', 'RFC822.SIZE'])
for msgid, data in response.iteritems():
    print '   ID %d: %d bytes, flags=%s' % (msgid,
                                            data['RFC822.SIZE'],
                                            data['FLAGS'])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although `IMAPClient` is a lot easier than using `imaplib`, it's still useful to know about the [IMAP protocol](http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt)

(Note, I've picked an arbitrary single email id to work with)

You can get the FROM via:

```
server.fetch([456], ['BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)]'])
# {456: {'BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)]': 'From: Facebook <register+mr4k25sa@facebookmail.com>\r\n\r\n', 'SEQ': 456}}
```

And the BODY via:

```
server.fetch([456], ['BODY[TEXT]'])
# {456: {'BODY[TEXT]': "Hey Jon,\r\n\r\nYou recently entered a new contact email [snip]", 'SEQ': 456}}
```

However, what's generally easier is to do:

```
import email
m = server.fetch([456], ['RFC822'])
msg = email.message_from_string(m[456]['RFC822'])
print msg['from']
# Facebook <register+mr4k25sa@facebookmail.com>
from email.utils import parseaddr
print parseaddr(msg['from'])
# ('Facebook', 'register+mr4k25sa@facebookmail.com')
print msg.get_payload()
# content of email...
```

Just be wary of where the payload includes attachments or is multipart...

Comment: Thank you for this. How would I tie this into a `for` loop for use in my code? I tried a couple things and it returned `{}`.

Comment: @David `server.fetch` returns a dictionary of msg_id->things you asked for... so given `msgs = server.fetch(...)', you can do `for msg_id, stuff in msgs.iteritems()`

Answer (score 0):

message body is found like this (im going to use a loop to get print each not deleted message body):

```
  for i in server[0].split():
      body = server.fetch(i,"BODY[TEXT]")
      print(body)
```

This should do it for the message body...

Comment: I got this error. 

`for i in server[0].split():`

`TypeError: 'IMAPClient' object does not support indexing`

Comment: Sorry, I am doing this away from code I've written. Try response[0].split() instead?

Answer (score 0):

IMAPClient is a fairly low-level lib, so you are still must to know IMAP protocol.

You can try to use more high level IMAP library: [imap_tools](https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools)

- Parsed email message attributes
- Query builder for searching emails
- Work with emails in folders (copy, delete, flag, move, seen)
- Work with mailbox folders (list, set, get, create, exists, rename, delete, status)
- No dependencies